# CSS DIV Overflow

Tags: css, html, overflow

Site: http://partsconsign.com/parts/?custid=1

I don't know what happened.  All of a sudden, without changing the css, when I expand the "browse" categories, they overflow outside of the containing divs.  Here is the css of the divs:

```
.bodyArea
{
    width: 900px;
    background-image:url(/images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    min-height: 900px;
}

.pageArea
{
    background-image: url(../images/page_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 95%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 700px;
    height:auto;
}

#partCat {
    width: 775px;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I don't see why expanding these divs would cause any kind of overflow.  None of these divs have any absolute positioning.  What am I doing wrong?  #partcat is within .pageArea, which is within .bodyArea.  I've looked through many questions asked previous here, but all of them seem to have slightly different issues.  Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `div` is fixed on `30px` height. Remove the height from this part

```
<div style="height: 30px; width: 100%">
```

<sub>Tested through the firebug, **IT WORKS**</sub>

Comment: Thanks Starx.  I had an unclosed div that was limited to 30px.  Other than scanning through divs in the code, is there a quick way to find unclosed divs like that?